# Is it possible to bound $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$-functions around zero by $a |x|^{-3/2 + \gamma}$ for $a,\gamma >0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

With the question in the title I mean this: Pick an $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$. Can one then find positive constants $a$, $\varepsilon$, and $\gamma$ such that 
$$
|f(x)| \leq a |x|^{-3/2 + \gamma}
$$
for almost all $x \in B_\varepsilon (0)$?

I am trying to turn the folklore statement "$f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$ behaves in the worst case like $a |x|^{-3/2 + \gamma}$ around $0$" into a rigorous one.

In order to answer my question positively, I aimed at a contradiction but didn't succeed. However, I also couldn't prove that
$$
\frac{e^{-x^2}}{|\sin\frac{1}{|x|}|^{-3/2 + \delta}},
$$
what seems to be a counterexample if $\delta > 0$ is sufficiently small, lies in $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$ at all.

Any help concerning my specific question but also references or general remarks are highly appreciated!

Comment: It's usually easier to work with simple functions - try constructing something of the form $f = \sum_n a_n \chi_{B(1/n,r_n)}$. You can first choose $a_n$ to give $f$ any growth rate you like as $x \to 0$, and then choose $r_n$ shrinking fast enough to keep the $L^2$ norm bounded.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis : Thanks a lot for the quick reply, which really helped. I worked out your suggestion and understand the mechanism now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct counterexample you can take
$$f(x) = |x|^{-3/2} \, (\log|x|)^\alpha$$
for small $x$ and a suitable $\alpha$.

Before you have further guesses, one can find a function in $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ with a singularity in any open set. Indeed, fix a nonnegative function $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ with a singularity at $0$. For an enumeration $\{q_i\}_{i \in \mathbb N}$ of $\mathbb Q^3$, consider
$$
g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{2^i} f(x - q_i).$$
This function belongs to $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$ and has a singularity at each rational number.

Comment: I was having further guesses... Thank you! Are you sure you got the signs of the exponents in your first equation right?

Comment: No, all numbers are correct only up to signs ;) Of course, it should be $-3/2$.